# how to make one p:datatable column be an expanded treenode

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-datatable

I want to have a `p:datatable` which contains one column having a treenode in each cell. How should I implement this? I'm new to jsf/primefaces. Any example is really appreciated. Thanks for any help!

```
   col1   |    col2
-------------------------------------------
   data1  |    node1
          |      |--- node2
          |      |--- node3
          |             |--- node4
------------------------------------------
   data2  |    node5
          |      |--- node6
---------------------------------------------
```

Here is my original datatable with all String columns:

```
    <p:dataTable id="datatable" value="#{userData.dataList}" var="data">
        <p:columns value="#{userData.dataTableColumns}" var="column">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
            </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{data[column.property]}" />                      
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: By putting a `p:tree` in there instead of an `h:outputText`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But the rest of columns are still String. If I change it to p:tree, the rest of columns will show  "Cannot convert 0 of type class java.lang.String to interface org.primefaces.model.TreeNode".

Comment: Have both a `p:tree` and a `h:outputText` there and use the `rendered` attribute based on your `column.property`.